# Ukraine bans entry for Russian men. Can I get the cost of my ticket refunded?

Tags: refunds, ukraine, visa-bans

I hold Russian passport and was meant to travel to Ukraine for Christmas. However, their government banned all Russian men aged from 18 to 60 from entering the country. Am I eligible to get my tickets refunded? Or do I have a case for insurance claim?

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your ticket. For a normal economy ticket, the airline will be unlikely to refund you anything, but you may be able to get partial or full credit for future flights. You may be able to talk them into waiving a change fee. Read the fare rules and call the airline.

This may be case for an insurance claim, provided you actually bought travel insurance for this trip. If you did: read the insurance contract and see what is covered. If you can't figure it out, call them.

Comment: Insurance contracts normally exclude consequences of riots, wars, political crisises etc., usually somewhere in smallprint between page 10 and 10.000...

Comment: @Rg7xgW6acQ3g: hence my suggestion to read the contract and/or call

Comment: It's common to be able to get a refund of airport fees and taxes if you have to cancel a ticket (although there may be an administration fee). It will depend on the airline and country but it's always worth trying or having a look at the terms and conditions.

Comment: The question is moot: RUssians are **NOT** banned from entering by air, regardless of what the media claims

Answer (score 2):

Actually the ban does **NOT** apply to RUssians entering Ukraine by air, as confirmed to me by both IATA (who run an airline database mentioning such things) and the DPSU (Ukrainian border agency).

From IATA:

> Dear Mr. Devecseri,
>
> I would like to inform you that, regardless of what you may read in the media, our sources in Ukraine have informed us that the imposed restrictions do not affect Russians arriving by air.
>
> Kind regards

So you're still allowed to enter, as long as you fly.

Comment: Could you please substantiate your answer with links to the official sources you consulted? [Gazeta.ru](https://www.gazeta.ru/social/2018/11/28/12076123.shtml) reports that male Russian citizens were already mass denied entry by air a few days *before* the official introduction of the ban, although with some exceptions. [24tv.ua](https://24tv.ua/zaborona_rosiyanam_vyizdu_v_ukrayinu_kogo_i_v_yakih_vipadkah_ne_vpuskatimut_prikordonniki_n1072597) supports that claim as well and lists only a handful of special circumstances under which the entry *may* be granted.

Comment: @undercat No links; it was by email to both IATA's TIMATIC department (remember airlines get heavily fined if transporting inadmissible passengers, so TIMATIC does mention entry bans) and DPSU at Borypsil

Comment: In this case can you provide the content of those e-mails in your answer? Good Stackexchange answers find their strength in verifiable facts, not hearsay.

Comment: @undercat Edited. The Email from the DPSU is in Ukrainian and not copy-pastable